# Calculating new velocities of 2 (or, if known, 3)-dimensional spheres (NOT infinitesimally small) after ellastic collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, vectors

I'm trying to calculate the final velocities of two 2D spheres with radius r1 & r2 colliding at some point on the perimeter (or surface area for 3D) of each sphere. How does one do this, taking into account the fact that the spheres don't always collide head on at their center of mass?

(I know this question has been answered many times for infinitesimally small point particles).

Would [this](https://atmos.illinois.edu/courses/atmos100/userdocs/3Dcollisions.html) just work? Or does this assume that the balls are infinitesimally small?

Comment: A sphere is 3D a circle is 2D.

Comment: I am aware, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link for the 3D case will work fine for a 2D case. The concept is the same, you just don’t have z components. Be careful though - note that all the equations in your link only address velocity, and mass is only noted in a caption on a diagram as a weighting factor (nice pun by the author).

You are calculating the velocities, in which case, as Pim notes, the standard momentum and energy equations are fine. If you want to also determine positions, you’ll need to worry about the radii (radiuses) and where the centers of mass are in each circle.

Comment: How would I calculate position as well?

Answer (score 0):

You still have conservation of linear momentum and kinetic energy, and if you know the angle at which they got you can still solve the problem.

$m_1\vec{v_1}+m_2\vec{v_2} = m_1\vec{u_1}+m_2\vec{u_2}$

And:

$\frac{m_1\vec{v_1}^2}{2}+\frac{m_2\vec{v_2}^2}{2} =  \frac{m_1\vec{u_1}^2}{2}+\frac{m_2\vec{u_2}^2}{2}$

Comment: I think this assumes that the distance between the two centers of mass can be less than the sum of the radii.

Comment: Your problem does or these equations do?

Comment: Because I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Your equations and the source I provided

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say as we approximate the spheres as point masses when in fact they have dimensions. But since the objects are perfectly spherical it doesn't matter and with these equations you'll get the correct results. This is after all the definition of an elastic collision.

Comment: @maxbear123 if the distance is larger than the sum of the radii, there is no collision

Comment: As @fqq mentioned there would indeed not even be a collision but I think you meant that we assume the spheres to be point masses right?

Comment: @fqq less than the sum of the radii

Comment: @maxbear123 still wouldn't matter, because even if there were to be a slight indentation in either of the spheres, these laws would still have to hold as it is an elastic collision where kinetic energy and linear momentum are conserved.